# How to write a class instantiable form both synchronous and asyncio code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-asyncio

I am trying to build a class that's instantiable from both "standard" (i.e.: non `asyncio`) code and for `asyncio` coroutine.

Specifically some methods need to spawn `subprocess`es and wait for completion.
Difference is that, while subprocess is running I shouldn't block the whole program (other coroutines, if they exist, should be able to run).

This boils down to use plain:

```py
from subprocess import run
r = run(arg[0], args)
```

in "standard" code and:

```py
from asyncio import create_subprocess_exec
r = await create_subprocess_exec(*args)
t = await r.wait()
```

problem is I cannot `await` from standard non-`async` method *even if* a loop is running (I can test if loop is running to discriminate, but I don't know how to hook to the running loop, if any).

Comment: how does that relate to "a class that's instantiable" ? what class and what issues?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: Class, of course, is instantiable in both environments, but, unless I do something, it will block the whole program while subprocess is active. I thus need some means to **conditionally** run subprocess in an "asyncio friendly" way, otherwise some methods of the class will misbehave (block everything else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is not supported by asyncio, and it might not be possible at all. Sync and async functions differ not only in function names, but in fundamental semantics of values and function calls.

Superficially you could do this:

```
def _run_subprocess_sync(args):
    from subprocess import run
    return run(args[0], args)

async def _run_subprocess_async(args):
    from asyncio import create_subprocess_exec
    r = await create_subprocess_exec(*args)
    return await r.wait()

def run_subprocess(args):
    if asyncio.get_event_loop() is not None and asyncio.get_event_loop().is_running():
        return _run_subprocess_async(args)
    else:
        return _run_subprocess_sync(args)
```

Note that it's ok that in the async case `run_subprocess` doesn't await the call to `_run_subprocess_async` because it will return a coroutine object which its *caller* (presumably an `async def` function) will await.

The problem is that this approach won't get you very far because it will require similar `if`s at every level of the hierarchy. For example, if you have a function that calls `run_subprocess` and does something with its result, it will similarly have to come in two variants, a sync and an async one, and a switch between the two.

Comment: Your code looks like a race condition. What if the event loop stops between the if and the async call

Comment: @lhk Keep in mind that asyncio is fundamentally single-threaded. `get_event_loop()` returns the event loop associated with the current thread, and such association cannot be updated from a different thread. So if it returns non-None, it means that the event loop is either running in this thread or not at all. In both cases the event loop cannot stop running between the `if` and the async call, because `loop.stop()` can only be called from the thread that runs the event loop.

Comment: oh that's interesting. I thought the loop would stop automatically once it has run out of code to execute or wait on. Didn't know you had to stop it explicitly

Comment: @lhk You thought correctly (unless `run_forever` or [equivalent](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.Server.serve_forever) is used, but the logic remains: either we're running **inside** the loop, or the loop isn't running. If the former, the loop can't shut down between `if` and the async call (remember that it's in the same thread). If it's the latter, the loop can't *start* running between the `if` and the sync call because, again, we're in that same thread, and we're not starting it. When everything is single threaded, there's just no one to race *with*.

Comment: Oh true. That makes sense. Thanks for the explanations :)